# Xamarin Android Simple Input Text Popup

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the ability to make my own popup, with dialogs, but I don't need anything complex. I was wondering if there was a simple function I could call that would make a popup where the user entered text and then return to me that text for use.

Sorta like these [popups](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/pop-ups/)

But with one where the user would enter text.

Fairly new so if there is something like this I wouldn't mind an example to go with it. Thanks.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20693/edittext-in-alertdialog

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Android native UI, then you can easily create an *AlertDialog* and add a *EditText* to the dialog.

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
ad.setTitle ("Type text");
ad.setView(et); // <----
ad.show();
```